# Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSArray' to parameter of type 'NSString'

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I'm a newbie. I am trying to call videos from an array. I know I am mixing strings with objects. But I don't know what to replace it with. Here is the [incorrect] line of code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: _arrayVidSrc ofType:@".mp4" inDirectory:@"videos"]];
```

How do I fix it?

Here's the whole code block:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.titlelabel.text = self.titlecontents;
    self.navBar.title = self.titlecontents;


    //video load from array
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: _arrayVidSrc ofType:@".mp4"]];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];
    playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [playercontroller.moviePlayer play];
    playercontroller = nil;


}
```

Comment: depends, what do you want? the 0 1 2 3 4 ..n object from your array?

Comment: An NSString _is_ an object.  You are mixing up types.  The error tells you the parameter needs an NSString but the code is passing an NSArray.  I suggest getting a better, basic understanding of Objective-C and searching for this common error.  There must be hundreds of examples on SO using pathForResource.

Comment: I know it's wrong. I don't know how to fix it. I am trying to set the video called according to what a user clicked in a table cell. So, if the user clicked cell 2, they'd get video 2 (#1 in the array).

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Answer (score 2):

From the context I think you want to get the array of URL's for videos. If `_arrrayVidSrc` is an array, you should pass only one of its elements (e.g. try using `_arrayVidSrc[0]` in the incorrect line of code):

```
NSString * firstVideoFileName = _arrayVidSrc[0];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:firstVideoFileName
                                                                    ofType:@".mp4"]];
```

Comment: This is close. But, not quite. Thank you. Instead of setting it to a specific number in the array, can I set it based on what cell in the table the user clicked?

Comment: That would be something like `NSString * firstVideoFileName = _arrayVidSrc[indexPath.row];` Be sure to have as many array items as there are cells.